# Add static page into CMS

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system, laravel-5

I use laravel 5 with blade template engine. I want to create module to insert static pages as .zip archive which contains html, css, js and image files into my CMS. This should be helpful when user need create page with another company and don't have skills in laravel or dont need to know our project structure.

My current process looks like:

1. prepare .zip archive with structure:

   - assets

     - js
     - css
     - images
   - index.html

**Scenario:**

[image]

2. Open CMS and fill title, link (slug), category and put archive into file input. On save I unzip archive into `public/static_pages/__slug__/` and replace *index.html* links for resources (css, js, images) by prepend correct link. Link for this page look like `/page/{category_slug}/{slug}`

**Cases:**

That works, but sometimes I want to use layout e.g some pages use menu and footer, but other not. What should I do then?

I have some ideas:

1. convert html file into blade. During development we will add special
   comments like `<!-- section content -->`, `<!-- section menu -->` and
   convert it into blade template.
2. add correct blade file
3. add html and chose layout in CMS. If layout was chosen then use it and add into @section('content') our static page, if not - show static page without layout.
4. add html file with comments like `<!-- insert menu -->`, `<!-- insert content -->`. We should prepare some 'sections' in database or files and replace comments by prepared sections.

**Problems:**

In all cases I no have idea what about add css / js files in correct places (in html).

In case with layout - if we use layout, then we should have predefined jquery. So in static page we couldnt duplicate it, but during development we need it.

In case without layout - add every time jquery and global css inside archive, so we duplicate it on the server and can't cache it.

What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use the Less/Sass or task runner such as gulp you can manually add your assets files to the public folder :

```
public
|_css
|_js
```

in your views just simply link it to them as below:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

Or

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">
```

same for the scripts. you can get more information from here:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

i try to organize my theme files with a folder in my view named

> " layout"

then make the following files :

> master.blade.php, header.blade.php ,footer.blade.php

set you html header codes in header.blade.php and same for foooter you can set your master like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>

        @include('layout.header')


    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
<footer>
    @include('layout.footer')
</footer>
</html>
```

then in any of your view the blade files just write:

```
 @extends('layout.master')
@section('title','title of your page')
@section('content')
your body content
@stop
```